# Setting user permission to access resources laravel spatie

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles, laravel-permission

I'm attempting to limit access to a specific resource `HealthController`

I am using Spatie and Laravel. I have set up my routes such as this. Note the posts route works fine, but the health one does not do as I want.

**Routes:**

```php
Route::group( ['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
    Route::resource('health', 'HealthController');
});
```

**Model:**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Search\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Health extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function journal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Journal::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```php
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Authorizable;

class HealthController extends Controller
{
    use Authorizable;

    public function index()
    {
        return view('health.index')
    }
}
```

and finally, I have assigned the permissions in the database.

**Permissions table**

```php
33  view_healths    web 2019-06-14 11:21:56 2019-06-14 11:21:56
34  add_healths     web 2019-06-14 11:21:56 2019-06-14 11:21:56
35  edit_healths    web 2019-06-14 11:21:56 2019-06-14 11:21:56
36  delete_healths  web 2019-06-14 11:21:56 2019-06-14 11:21:56
```

**role_has_permissions table**

```php
33  1
34  1
35  1
```

and a DD out of the user confirms that I have the Admin role.

What am I missing here? When I visit the route I get:

> This access is unauthorized

Presumably because I don't have the correct permissions?

Comment: Can you add the code from your `Authorizable` trait to your question.

Comment: Are you using policies?